# Post a value from HttpPost Android to Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to post some value from my Android app to my Asp.Net Web Api. but I only get null in my Web Api, where do you think my problem is?

I have this code for android :

in MainActivity:

```
List<NameValuePair> IdsToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
for (Message item : messages) {
    IdsToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("messageIds", item.Id));               
}
parser.sendPostRequest(UpdateMessageStatuseURL ,IdsToSend);
```

in some other file:

```
public void sendPostRequest(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
```

and my Web Api:

```
public void Post([FromBody]int[] messageIds)
        {
            var dc = new SMSDataDataContext();
            foreach (var item in messageIds)
            {
                var message = dc.Messages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == item);
                if (message != null)
                {
                    message.Statuse = 1;
                    dc.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: where is null exactly ?

Comment: messageIds in Webapi Post

Comment: When I get stuck with errors like this I tend to setup a network between my development device and desktop and use either fiddler or wire shark to view the packets.  You can then view the data which is being posted.  Without looking too deeply into it, I assume the post data which is being sent isn't in the correct format, I'm sure it should be something along the lines of "messageIds[i]" instead of "messageIds" in the main activity, but as I said, its simply a quick glance.  Try replacing the for each with a for loop and giving the array items a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better of binding to a complex type.

```
public class YourModel
{
    public int[] messageIds { get; set; }
}

public void Post(YourModel model) { ... }
```

That will work. If for whatever reason, you cannot have a complex type, you will need to ensure the request message body is like this.

```
=1&=2&=3&=30
```

It might be wierd but this will bind to int[]. I do not know how you can submit this payload from Android but there must be a way. Easier way out will probably be using a complex type. BTW, FromBody will be needed only for simple types.